# How do I name parameters in my view so that an array gets built when I submit my form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, view, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

I’m using Rails 5.  I have this model

```
class Scenario < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :grading_rubric, optional: true
  has_many :confidential_memo
  has_many :scenario_roles, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :roles, :through => :scenario_roles
    …
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles
end
```

I’m dynamically creating role elements in my view, but am having trouble getting them all processed when they are submitted.  I submit the following form from the client

```
.   utf8:✓
.   authenticity_token:n2/51OSHlNP+1E7qnLku/gXtCjUk/MfMxwsrNpUirR2IbQddOzP1/OClL50ClCPvDNIowvdsqpVNmer37Egp4w==
.   scenario[title]:title #8
.   scenario[abstract]:abstract
.   scenario[roles][name]:wwz
.   scenario[roles][name]:aaa
.   authenticity_token:n2/51OSHlNP+1E7qnLku/gXtCjUk/MfMxwsrNpUirR2IbQddOzP1/OClL50ClCPvDNIowvdsqpVNmer37Egp4w==
```

See that I have two different parameters with the name “scenario[roles][name]”.  But on the server end, it only picks up one of the two parameters.  Here is what is in my log ...

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"n2/51OSHlNP+1E7qnLku/gXtCjUk/MfMxwsrNpUirR2IbQddOzP1/OClL50ClCPvDNIowvdsqpVNmer37Egp4w==", 
 "scenario"=>{"title"=>"title #8", "abstract"=>"abstract", "roles"=>{"name"=>"aaa"}}}
```

What do I need to name my parameters in my view so that multiple ones get picked up on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles` requires that parameters come as `roles_attributes`

So in the form you should have them like this

```
 scenario[roles_attributes][][name]
```

And in rails you'll receive in `params[:scenario][:roles_attributes]` an array of hashes, each having a name entry.